# Passing value between pages. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have 2 pages, one called details.page and the other, maps.page

In the first page, I have a declared a search input like so :

```
  <form method="get" id="form-search" data-ajax="true" action="maps.page">
            <input type="search" name="search" id="search" value=""/>
        </form>
```

And in my second page, maps.page, I have one declared like so :

```
  <form action="maps.page">
        <input type="search" name="search" id="search-field" value=""/>
        </form>
```

Now, I was assuming that when I type something in the search bar from my first page and hit enter, the search bar on maps.page would be populated with the value previously entered.

I am correctly redirected, but the search bar is empty.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT** : Also, I see in the URL that it seems to be working, because I can see what I searched in the URL like this : /maps.page?search=something

Comment: I think you need to read up on client-side and server-side scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few option in how to do this without using a back end script.

1) You can set the form method to GET so that the variables are passed in the address bar, then grab them on the other side using a script like the one below (this actually reads the address and then parses it for variables). After that, you can put that value in your input field.

```
var getVars = new Array();
var locvartemp = ( window.location.href.indexOf( "?" ) + 1 ) ? window.location.href.substr( window.location.href.indexOf( "?" ) + 1 ) : "";
locvartemp = locvartemp.split( "&" );
for( var x = 0; x < locvartemp.length; x++ ) {
    var lvTempVar = locvartemp[x].split( "=" );
    getVars[ unescape( lvTempVar[0] ) ] = unescape( lvTempVar[1] );
}
```

2) You can use the jQuery cookie plugin to set the value as a cookie prior to submitting the form and then read it on the other side and set it to your input field.

```
jQuery.cookie("myCookie", document.formName.myFieldName.value);
```

Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 1):

The value is not automatically filled. You need to print it from the server side.

```
  <form action="maps.page">
        <input type="search" name="search" id="search-field" value="<insert value>"/>
  </form>
```

Comment: Well that's the problem, I want to pass the value I see in my URL to the textbox.

Comment: use session to store the value, then in next page use session to read the value and set the value attribute of your search box. It can not populate automatically.

Comment: Don't use a session unless you want the data to persist. That way lies a pile of race conditions. The value is already in the query string for the second page, read it directly from there.

Answer (score 1):

> I was assuming that when I type something in the search bar from my first page and hit enter, the search bar on maps.page would be populated with the value previously entered.

That is what you are doing wrong.

The field will only be populated if you set the value attribute (or set the DOM value property after the element has been added to the DOM).

This is generally done using a server side process. The specifics depend on the language you are using to create that process, but do watch out for [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) as including unfiltered, unescaped user input will create a security hole.